# How to block interconnection of devices in LAN network?

Tags: connection, ping, router, lan

I want to block interconnections of devices in my network i.e in LAN one device should not be able to ping another device. I think for this I have to configure my router but i dont know the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For blocking interconnection of devices .

A feature is there in router(depend on router company) called Client Isolation .
find this feature probably present under wireless settings.
Just enable it .

BTW which router you are using.

Comment: CISCO.. Btw i have found that option. Thanks :)